# circular objects, illegal isArrayLike() invocation and Infinite $digest loop creating a <div> with ngReact

Tags: angularjs, dom, reactjs, clone, ngreact

[UPDATED Sept, 24]

I am trying to use ngReact instead of ngRepeat to improve performance when I modify my $watched array of objects.

For each object (a map marker) contained in the controller, I want to create a `<button>`, with the `marker.title` as text. For this purpose, I crated a React  component that $watches an array of markers. Such a  contains a list of , one for each marker. I supposed that the component will result *changed* only if I modify the list of markers, and then the list of buttons. However this is not the case.

```
[TypeError]: Illegal invocation
  at isArrayLike (angular.js:274)
  at forEach (angular.js:328)
  at copy (angular.js:886)

[Error]: [$rootScope:infdig] 10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting!
Watchers fired in the last 5 iterations: []
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.0-rc.0/$rootScope/infdig?p0=10&p1=%5B%5D
    at REGEX_STRING_REGEXP (angular.js:68)
    at Scope.parent.$get.Scope.$digest (angular.js:15340)
    at Scope.parent.$get.Scope.$apply (angular.js:15570)
    at (index):95
```

It seems that the list of the `<button>` created by the React component results always different, even if made by the same objects.

Now the weird part.. Actually,I add markers to the map using Json objects. When I add a Json object, the map create a `Marker` object, not jsonable cause it has a circular structure. I add this `Marker` object to my $watched array, to create the relative `<button>`... Maybe this is the cause of the `illegal isArrayLike()` error?

Here it is my React component (at the end of my post, there is the JSfiddle link)

HTML

```
    <!-- m_list is an attribute of $rootScope -->
    <poi-list list="m_list" />
```

JS

```
.value( "PoiList", React.createClass( {

  propTypes : {

    list: React.PropTypes.object.isRequired
  },

  render: function() 
   {
    var markers = this.props.list.map( function( marker, i ) 
        {//for each marker, create a button
         return React.DOM.button(  {
                                    className:'btn btn-default'                               
                                   }, marker.title
                                 ) ; 
        } );
    return React.DOM.div({}, markers);
    }


}))

.directive( 'poiList', function( reactDirective ) {
  return reactDirective( 'PoiList' );
} );
```

[this is a JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xg0Ln79q/1/) of my problem. A brief description:

- there are 2 arrays in the $rootScope. temp_list is used to temporarily push all the markers one by one. m_list is $watched by the react component.
- there is a MapBox directive with its controller. For each marker added to the map, it will be pushed in the temp_list.
- once all the markers have been loaded and temp_list is complete, this is cloned to m_list, so the react component can be updated.

thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution! The problem somehow is connected to the use of the map. In the watched array, I am not adding the Json markers, but I am adding the object marker created by MapBox.

```
map.featureLayer.setGeoJSON(json_markers_list);  // I pass an array of Json markers
map.featureLayer.on('layeradd', function(e) 
                {
                     var marker = e.layer;        // marker is anymore a json obj
                     ctrl.pushMarker(marker);  // marker now has a cyclic structure
                    });
```

The object marker created by MapBox, has a cyclic structure. For this reason, React cannot know if the old $watched array has changed since the last check, because it cannot perform `isArrayLike()` when cycle structure is present. So it rises an error (different in any browser) and considers the array always changed, generating the $digest infinite iteration.

My solution is using one array and one map. The array is $watched with just the information I need to display in the button

```
{'title': 'marker title', 'id':00001}
```

the map contains the real marker objects

```
{'00001' : {markerObj}}
```

and this is a working [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/o43e0nqp/1/) !   Click on a button and the marker object will be selected.

This question and solution is also poster on the forum of the  [official ng-react project](https://github.com/davidchang/ngReact/issues/104#issuecomment-144934646)